# Are My Emails Being Tracked? I Keep Getting The Google Apps Script Failures. Email Below And I Skipped Multiple Errors

Tags: google-apps-script

**Summary of failures for Google Apps Script: Save Emails and Attachments
@SaneLater
apps-scripts-notifications@google.com
5:34 AM (7 hours ago)
to me**

Your script, Save Emails and Attachments, has recently failed to finish successfully. A summary of the failure(s) is shown below. To configure the triggers for this script, or change your setting for receiving future failure notifications, click here.

The script is used by the document [Addon] GA02 Save Emails.

Summary:

Error Message   Count
Authorization is required to perform that action.   97

*Start  Function    Error Message   Trigger End
10/19/21 3:04:33 PM IST webtrigger_SaveEmails   Authorization is required to perform that action.   time-based  10/19/21 3:04:33 PM IST
10/19/21 3:19:33 PM IST webtrigger_SaveEmails   Authorization is required to perform that action.   time-based  10/19/21 3:19:33 PM IST

Sincerely,

Google Apps Script

Need help? Visit the Google Apps Script documentation. Please do not reply to this message. (c) 2021 Google

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Remove the addon

Comment: If you're using gmail, your e-mails *will* be tracked by google whatever you do. And you can easily assume that that data will be shared with third party but only "in order to improve your experience".

Answer (score 0):

If possible, try to force the script to manually run once from the code editor so that you can get the authorization popups and agree to them.